# Equivalent of ajax petition in PHP

Tags: php

How can I pass data between scripts in PHP without `$_SESSION`? I need to send the information specifying a *method*, the thing is that this is a script that will run only on the server side, without interaction with user. Right now, I have a view in which the user do the operations, for that I'm using the ajax provided by jQuery, I have:

```
             $.ajax({
                url: "action.php",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "html",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    method: "sendMessage",
                    target: target,
                    message: message
                }});
```

that works pretty well, but I need to remove the view and the interaction with the user, and make that works without JavaScript. So I want to know, which is the equivalent in PHP to call the script *`action.php`* and send it all the data whit the specified method?

Comment: You need to do a HTTP request in PHP. One way to do that is to use a library for it, for example the very good guzzle library: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/

Comment: `<form method="post" action="action.php">`

Comment: Use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), I mostly use for better controlling of requests.

Comment: @Jost and Adam thank you very much! I will check it

Comment: @AdamAzad: Guzzle uses curl under the hood (and can use other stuff). And it's very flexible as well :-)

Answer (score -1):

1. Write your function as a [function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php).
2. [`include()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) the file containing your function.
3. Just call the function passing whatever data you like as an [argument](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php).

If you also need to present it as a front end view, then you would write a separate wrapper script and put that on a publicly accessible URL.